# Assign specific agent on Azure DevOps YAML Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-release-task

I am trying to assign a specific agent on my agent pool but I don't know how to do it. Does anyone know it?

I tried with this but doesn't work:

```
- stage: Deploy
  pool: alm-aws-pool
    agent.name: deploy-05-agent1
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The pool name needs to add to the `name` field, then you could add `demands`. You may try the following Yaml Code:

```
stages:
- stage: Deploy
  pool: 
   name: AgentPoolName(e.g. alm-aws-pool)
   demands:
    - agent.name -equals Agentname (e.g. deploy-05-agent1)
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    steps:
    - script: echo Building!
```

Please check if it could work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't make the same mistake as me, enclosing the agent name in quotes. It will fail :(
So don't write `- agent.name -equals 'Agentname'`

Comment: @Kevin would you happen to know teh answer to my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77162832/fail-to-download-a-file-from-ado-secure-files-storage-using-ado-rest-api

Comment: Following up on @Michael's comment - if your agent name has spaces in it, `agent.name -equals Agent Name` unexpectedly works just fine.

Answer (score 8):

Use demands

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

```
- stage: Deploy   
    pool: alm-aws-pool
    demands:
    - agent.name -equals deploy-05-agent1
```

Comment: Hi @Kontekst this does not work for my i have this error: Mapping Values are not allowed in this context