# Fail to download a file from ADO Secure Files storage using ADO REST API

Tags: rest, azure-devops

The docs on secure files API are missing on their site.

I got these directions online:

> Get the Secure File ID: Before downloading a secure file, you need to know its ID. This can usually be found within the UI, or you can list all secure files using the REST API.

> Acquire the VstsSecureFileTicket: This is a ticket that allows downloading of a secure file for a specific time:

> `POST` `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/securefiles/{secureFileId}/acquireticket?api-version=7.1-preview.1`

> Download the Secure File: Use the acquired VstsSecureFileTicket to download the file:

> `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/securefiles/{secureFileId}?ticket={ticket}&api-version=7.1-preview.1`

I am not new and have successfully used ADO API many times, I got the list of files along with their IDs using the `/_apis/distributedtask/securefiles?api-version=7.0-preview.1` endpoint, but when I try to get the download ticket, I get `401 Unauthorized`.

UPD:
I generated a PAT with higher (full) secure files permissions.
I can still get a list of secure files along with their ids as before, but trying to get a download ticket now results in `404 Not Found` instead of 401 `Unauthorized`. Go figure.